# Clone of old Raspberry Pi image not working on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I have an early Raspberry Pi (mid-2013) running Raspbian. I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 model B.

I cloned the SD card from the old Pi onto a micro SD card to run in the new Pi, but it's not booting. I googled it and apparently older versions of Raspbian won't run on the newer Pi. I tried updating Raspbian on the old Pi and then tried cloning it across again, but it still won't boot on the new Pi.

Does anyone have any ideas? The new Pi definitely works as it booted with a new version of Raspbian on another card.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A mid 2013 Pi would probably be running Raspbian Wheezy which I don't think supports the new hardware on the Pi 3. You would need to make sure the firmware is updated for the Pi 3, try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rpi-update
sudo reboot
```

The best way to get a Raspberry Pi 3 running would be to download the latest image for [Raspbian Jessie](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) from the official source and write this to the SD card.

There is a forum post on how to upgrade to Jessie but this path is not officially supported. It has been reported to work with a fresh install but if you have installed applications this could be a problem. Have a look at this forum post for details: [How to upgrade a Wheezy image to Jessie](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=121880)

Comment: Thanks - I tried doing those updates but it still won't boot on the Pi 3. Is there another way to update to Jessie without losing the programs I already have installed etc?

Comment: Upgrading to Jessie is possible, you need to change the sources list, but on the officially Raspberry Pi website they recommend a fresh image

Comment: If you used a fresh image though, wouldn't you lose all programs etc you've already installed?

Comment: Yes, a fresh install would not copy your programs. I have added a link to a forum post that describes the upgrade process that may work. What programs do you need to keep?

Answer (score 1):

RPi3 does not support Wheezy. The RPi3 came in March 2016, after the last release of Wheezy (May 2015). You should switch to jessie

Comment: Is there another way to update to Jessie without losing the programs I already have installed etc?

Comment: I don't have enough space here to explain everything but there's a great tutorial here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27858/upgrade-to-raspbian-jessie

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go.